# Search XML node value without knowing parent node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I want to search for an XML nodes value without knowing the node's parent.  I read in XML docs that to search for a value, you can use the following syntax:

```
//book[price>35.00]
```

This selects all the book elements anywhere in the xmldocument that have a price element with a value greater than 35.00

What I want to do is not reference the book node but instead find all price elements anywhere in the xmldocument with a value greater than 35.00.  How do I write this?

I am using XmlDocument classes in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this XPath: `//price[. > 35.00]`

Answer (score 1):

Kirill has shown an XPath approach - I would personally try to use LINQ to XML (so `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`) if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher.

You'd then use:

```
var prices = doc.Descendants("price")
                .Where(x => (decimal?) x > 35m);
```